# Suming multiple cells that may not be number

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am struggling with this for a while and would like to receive your help. What I am trying to do is to sum the values of D column multiplied by value of E column, but not just sum elements of D and then multiply by sum of elements of E but first, multiply elements of each row, so for ex D2 * E2, D3 * E3 etc and then sum up result of multiplication of from each row. I tried to achieve this with arrayFormula and sum, but the problem is that in both column there may appear not a number, but character 'X', so the solution I created will not work. I was trying to use sumif alongside with arrayformula but it is not working and have no idea what to try to change to make this work. The formula I came up with is:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMif(D2:D24*E2:E24;"<>*X*"))`

Example data:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try simple:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(A1:A*B1:B)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(if(D2:D24="X",0,D2:D24)*if(E2:E24="X",0,E2:E24)))
```

I am using the if() function to check for occurrence of "X" within the array, and replace it with 0 if "X" is found.

Comment: That is not working for me, I get formula parse error. Column type of these column is number so I thought it is a problem with comparing to "X" in if and tried to use TO_TEXT function but still get same error.